# -2 base conversion algorithm suggestion

Tags: ruby, math, radix

I am trying to convert an integer to base -2, but in Ruby `.to_s(-2)` doesn't get accepted. Do you have any other solutions to convert a number to -2 base?

Comment: Write the algorithm utilizing integer division. [Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base#Calculation) describes this pretty well, including the potential pitfall with negative remainders.

Comment: Hmmm. -2 to what power equals, say,  8?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: 8 is represented in base -2 as (-2)^4 + (-2)^3 (so the corresponding bit string would be 11000, from msb to lsb).

Comment: Here's a one-liner in Python; I'm sure it can easily be translated to Ruby. `negabinary = lambda n: negabinary(-(n>>1)) + str(n&1) if n else ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson)'s comment:

```
def negabinary(n)
  return negabinary(-(n>>1)) + (n & 1).to_s if n != 0
  return ''
end
```